# Where, besides Scheme reports (RnRS) has Stoy's notation for auxiliary semantic functions been used?

Tags: notation, denotational-semantics

The denotational semantics of R4RS, R5RS and R7RS Scheme (included in the language report) uses the same notation that was used by J. E. Stoy in his book, *"Denotational Semantics: the Scott-Strachey approach to programming language theory"*. This notation includes:

- $s\downarrow k$ for the $k$th element of the sequence $s$
- $\#s$ for the length of sequence $s$
- $s\dagger k$ for dropping of the $k$ first elements of sequence $s$
- $s\S t$ for concatenation of sequences

It seems quite terse, and potentially very cryptic.

I am aware of only one other book that uses this notation -- Christian Queinnec's *"Lisp in Small Pieces"*.

I'd like to know if there are any other introductory books besides Stoy's and Queinnec's which uses it -- and also if it's used in any other works defining denotational semantics of languages, other than Scheme.